# Sidebar widgets are over the content in mobile mode, how can I fix it?

Tags: widgets, css, sidebar, mobile, responsive

I'm building a website by modifying the Dazzling theme on WordPress, and I'm having a problem with the sidebar widgets (Text). Here's the link to the website:
http://theaerospecialist.com/

The website is working fine in full window, but when I try to restore the window down to a small size, or when I visualize it from a smartphone the sidebar gets over the main content.

Here's how it looks in resized window:
[image]

As you can see, the content from the first widget in the sidebar gets stretched over the blog content. I've tried to disable the first widget, but then the next widget content gets stretched over the first. How can I fix this? Do you know at least which file I should look with the WordPress Editor?

Comment: this is not a WordPress question is more of a CSS question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's css problem apply some css to it, you can do the following when the browser window is smaller than 800px it will hide the overflow of that div, you can simply apply it without media query as well.

add this in your `style.css`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
div#box {
    overflow: hidden;
}
}
```